# Extracting narrow-band ZigBee signals(4 MHz) from a wide-band WiFi signal(20 MHz)?

Tags: filtering, multirate

I am planning the following.

First sample the 20 MHz WiFi channel (WiFi channel-1 in figure).

Put band pass filters (5 MHz wide) around each of the ZigBee center frequencies (11, 12, 13, 14).

Re-sample the chunks to 4 MHz.

Is there anything wrong with this approach ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a little bit of context (or a link), and describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am working on a SIC module which will first decode WiFi and then after cancelling the interference, decode ZigBee.

Answer (score 1):

> Put band pass filters (5 MHz wide) … Re-sample the chunks to 4 MHz.

Don't do that! If you reduce the sampling rate to 4 MS/s, you need to filter to 4 MHz bandwidth anyway. So you could instead just use 4 MHz wide filters and get rid of the resampling filter.

Comment: Ok but in order to decode Zigbee I need samples @4MHz. I am working on a SIC module which will first decode WiFi and then after cancelling the interference, decode ZigBee.